# how to make a httpwebrequest on application launch in wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

how to  make a httpwebrequest on application launch  in  windows phone 7 and 8  synchronous so that based on the response from the server  can change the  start page .

```
private void Application_Launching(object sender, LaunchingEventArgs e)
 {
   // http request and respose  b
   // based on response  select the start page  
 }
```

Comment: only async requests are supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well as only `async` requests are performed. For **`WP7`**, you can perform `async` request and wait for `response`, based on `response` you can navigate to Pages as per you logic. To do that, in **`Startup Page`**:

In `class's constructor` call method like **`NavigateToPages();`**

Now in that method you can call the `http reqeust` you want and when you get `response` navigate to page like,

```
void NavigateToPage()
{
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    client.DownloadStringCompleted += (object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e) => 
    {
        var result = e.Result;
        //Navigate to page
    }
    client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("<your web request"));
}
```

This will wait till you get `response`. Meanwhile to show user that you're requesting `web service` you can add **`ProgressIndicator`** and before starting `web request` start it and just put "Fetching Response" as `text` and in the `response` make it `empty ""`. Also it is recommended you should call request in `try-catch-finally` block. So that if internet is down or problem getting `reponse` app should not crash.

I done this for WP7, I think should work for WP8 as well. Try it out if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Well you cannot make a synchronous call.

you can do is the next best thing. Make the method async and use the PCL version of http client.

this would allow you logic to flow in a synchronous like way (still async though).

Answer (score 0):

As @Hermit Dave suggest, you cannot make synchronous http request in WP, and making it async will break your current application logic. The application execution will probably exit Application_Launching method before the call return response.

Maybe you can create a default page as start page displaying some sort of loading animation and some hint to give user idea of what the application is currently processing. In that page make async http request. And in the callback, redirect to proper page based on the response.